# Route Model Binding not working

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel, crud

I'm trying to use Route Model Binding for Simple CRUD but Update And Delete Function Not Working. and I'm Using laravel 5.5

```
Route::resource('admin/file','AdminController');
```

My View For Edit and Delete Buttons

```
<a href="{{ route('file.edit', ['id'=>$file->id]) }}">

<form action="{{ route('file.destroy', ['id'=>$file->id]) }}" method="post">
   {{method_field('DELETE')}}
   {{csrf_field()}}
   <button type="submit" class="delete">delete</button>
</form>
```

My Resource Controller :

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Files;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

Store Work Fine

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'title'=>'required',
        'body'=>'required',
        'price'=>'required',
        'linkFile'=>'required',
    ]);

     Files::create($request->all());
    return redirect(route('file.index'));
}
```

But Edit and Delete Not Working

```
public function edit(Files $files)
{
   return view('admin.edit',compact('files'))->with('title','Edit File');
}

public function destroy(Files $files)
{
    $files->delete();
    return redirect(route('file.index'));
}
```

My Model:

```
protected $table='files';

protected $fillable=[
    'title','body','price','linkFile'
];
```

When I Delete Button Nothing Happens and Edit as Same

If I Add `dd($files)` at First Column for Edit and Delete Function Then Response Will be `[]` and There's No Error for handle

Here My Route Lists

[image]

Anyone Can help Please?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Finally, after 2 days I found my answer and I would like to provide my answer here for everyone who maybe has the same problem.

#### For route binding to work, your type-hinted variable name must match the route placeholder name

For example my edit method

Here is my route URI for the edit

```
admin/file/{file}/edit
```

As you can see there is a `{file}` placeholder in the route definition, so the corresponding variable must be called `$file`.

```
public function edit(Files $file)
{
   return view('admin.edit',compact('file'));
}
```

Comment: This solved my issue too. This is such important information hidden in docs

Comment: This helped me as well.  I had a camelCase version of the variable in the controller which didn't resolve.  Thanks!

Comment: it works like a charm

Comment: I kept trying to use {$id} and all variations of the id, this saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 15):

I´ve stumbled across this again. I´m not sure if this was my own mistake or if this middlerware is missing by default.

Im using Laravel 8 and develop an API. I always got an empty array back as a response, when I tried to call a route that should implicitly bind to a model.

**TL;DR**
Check if the `Kernel.php` file `$routedMiddlewareGroups` api array has the `SubstituteBindings::class` added to it. Otherwise your requests won´t get resolved correctly.

The request to the API | Get User by ID | Frontend, Vue.js

`UserComponent.vue`

```
methods: {
        close() {
            $('#user-modify-modal').modal('hide');
        },
        open() {
            $('#user-modify-modal').modal({backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false});

            this.fetchUserData(this.params.id);
        },
        async fetchUserData(id) {
            await axios
            .get('users/${this.params.id}')
            .then((result) => {
                this.user = result.data;
            }).catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });
        }
    },
```

Heres how I set up my API protected routes:

routes/`api.php`

```
//protected routes | API
Route::group(['middleware' => ['api', 'cors', 'json.response', 'auth:api'], 'prefix' => 'v1'], function() {
    Route::post('/logout', [ApiLoginController::class, 'logout']);

    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });
    Route::get('/users', [UserController::class, 'index']);
    //the function im Testing...
    Route::get('users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'show']);
    Route::post('/users', [UserController::class, 'store']);
    Route::put('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'update']);
    Route::delete('/users/{user}', [UserController::class, 'show']);
});
```

`UserController.php`

```
...
/**
     * Get user by ID
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param User $user
     * @return void
     */
    public function show(User $user) {

        return response()->json($user);
    }
...
```

**Without this middlerware `SubstituteBinding::class` the Implicit Binding will NOT work!**

Make sure to check your kernel / api settings

`Kernel.php`

```
 /**
     * The application's route middleware groups.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $middlewareGroups = [
        'web' => [
            \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
            \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
            //\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class,
            \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],

        'api' => [
            'throttle:120,1',
            EncryptCookies::class,
            AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
            \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,

            \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        ],
    ];
```

Now when calling

```
http://localhost/api/v1/users/1
```

It returns the correct user data.

Comment: this worked for me! THANKS a lot , I've added JWT authenticating with different guards & middlewares set up. & unexpectedly everything fell down.

Comment: Oh my god, thanks for sharing this! It's been driving me crazy!

Answer (score 14):

I know this problem already has a solution, but let me add some knowledge that might be useful to others...

As [the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters) says, when using resource controllers, the resource routes will use parameters based on the "singularized" name of the resource. In the case of the question, since @siros was using the "file" resource name (singular form) in the route, the binding name in the controller method should be "file", although his model is named `Files`. If he attempted to use:

```
Route::resource('admin/files','AdminController');
```

The controller would still need `Files $file` to work, since `file` is the singularized form of `files`.

**However**, there is other (and more elegant) solution to the problem. You can change the type-hinted variable in the URL by providing a `parameters` option in the configuration of the route, as shown [in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters), which would automatically apply for the `show`, `edit`, `update` and `destroy` methods. This will let you keep the variable name in your controller matching the model name, for example.

So, in this case, @siros could use this in the routes file:

```
Route::resource('admin/file','AdminController', [
    'parameters' => [
        'file' => 'files'
    ]
]);
```

And he could use this in the controller:

```
public function edit(Files $files)
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: this is awesome! Was struggling to get the resource way to work.

Comment: in laravel 8: ```Route::resource('file', AdminController::class)->parameters(['file' => 'files']);```