# Laravel - DELETE method is not support for a delete route

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm a complete beginner at laravel and am currently making a simple admin panel. I have a grid that shows users (name, email, etc...) and the problem I have is probably stupid but I can't figure it out. I created a controller method for deleting a user:

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->delete();

        return redirect('/admin')->with('success', 'User has been deleted');
    }
```

And defined route as this:

```
Route::post('/admin/delete/{id}', 'AdminController@destroy')    
    ->middleware('is_admin')    
    ->name('admin.destroy');
```

and to delete a user in grid, I used form in my view and even setup headers:

```
<td>
<form href="{{ route('admin.destroy', $user->id)}}" method="post">
   @method('DELETE')
   @csrf
   <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

And everytime I press button for deleting a user, I get this:

```
The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

I just can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I tried changing route type to post but I get the same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307094/route-model-binding-not-working check this link..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your form does not contain an `action`, so it will submit it to the same url as it's on, which is only GET/HEAD.

Try this instead:

```
<form action="{{ route('admin.destroy', $user->id)}}" method="post">
   @method('DELETE')
   @csrf
   <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Comment: Additionally to the issue pointed out by PtrTon, your route is defined as `POST` but you are adding `@method('DELETE')` in your form. It won't break because the form itself is using `POST` and Laravel only checks for the presence of the `_method` input created by `@method` if you use `DELETE` or `PUT` as method for your route. Anyway, you should either update your route to `Route::post(...)` or remove the method helper in your view. I'd recommend using a delete route, as this is the correct way to do it.